# Missing Event type MouseUp

Tags: eclipse-rap

In the following scenario a Event from type MouseUp is missing.

The base to reproduce is this code (using rap 3.0)

```java
@Override
protected void createContents(Composite parent) {
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(1, false);
    parent.setLayout(gl);

    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);

    Composite above = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    above.setLayout(gl);
    above.setLayoutData(gd);
    Button buttonAbove = new Button(above, SWT.TOGGLE);
    buttonAbove.setText("above");

    Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.TOGGLE);
    button.setText("start");
    addListener(button);

    Composite bottom = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    bottom.setLayout(gl);
    bottom.setLayoutData(gd);
    Button buttonBottom = new Button(bottom, SWT.TOGGLE);
    buttonBottom.setText("bottom");
}

private void addListener(Button button) {
    Listener listener = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SWT.MouseDown:
                    System.out.println("MouseDown");
                    break;
                case SWT.MouseUp:
                    System.out.println("MouseUp");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    button.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
    button.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, listener);
}
```

1. go with the cursor over the button `start`
2. press the mouse button and keep it pressed
3. drag the cursor to the right, over the button `bottom` or to the composite `buttom` and release the MouseButton --> the Event from type `SWT.MouseUp` is fired
4. go with the cursor over the button `start` again
5. press the mouse button and keep it pressed
6. drag the cursor over the button `above` or over the composite `above` and release the mouse button --> the Event is not fired

I found this problem in a more complex way while doing drag'n'drop of a Button and this seem to be the root of the problem.

In a SWT Application a MouseUp Event is always thrown.

Is this a bug in RAP?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if it works in SWT but not in RAP then it is a bug in RAP. I suggest to [file a bugzilla](https://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/)

Comment: created a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488755)
already fixed